# SwiftUI .tabViewStyle(.page) for macOS

Tags: macos, swiftui

How to create a paged scroll view on macOS?

on iOS this can be done

```
struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        TabView {
            Text("First")
            Text("Second")
            Text("Third")
            Text("Fourth")
        }
        .tabViewStyle(.page)
        .indexViewStyle(.page(backgroundDisplayMode: .always))
    }
}
```

but this is not available on macOS... on macOS only `.tabViewStyle(.automatic)` and this is not a paged scroll view

Comment: you need to implement it yourself. Based on TabViewStyle protocol

Answer (score 1):

for the actual macOS version, there are no supported styles except automatic.

You can check all supported styles on the following page:

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/tabviewstyle/automatic

There is also none of information on the TabViewStyle protocol, so it could be a bit challenging to implement your own style:

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/tabviewstyle

In summary: currently there is no way to get tab-pages on macOS until 14.0 including.

You can implement it yourself by using swipe gestures. But it will take some time.

P.S. I did a brief search on the web, didn't find any useful implementation of such UI element.